# How to condense a bunch of IF statements using a List - is it possible?

Tags: c#, list

So I have two "documents" that both have allot of properties. One document is an instance of a document that has been filled out.  I need to check if there is a 'Value" in the property (since they are mainly nullable int?) and if so assign the value of the current property to the property of the other document.

Example

```
if (documentA.FirstProperty.HasValue)
{
    documentB.FirstProperty = documentA.FirstProperty
}
```

But is there a way to make this clearner?  I thought maybe I could create a list of the document type and using a foreach loop and check if the current property has a value and if so assign it to the new document.

With having already acquired an instance of a document called **oldDocument**

Example:

```
List<oldDocument> listOfProperties = new List<oldDocument>();

foreach (var property in listOfProperties)
{
    if (property.HasValue)
    {
        documentB.property = documentA.property;
    }
}
```

Where the variable "property" in the foreach loop would represent the name of the property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use linq for that.

```
var nullProps = doc1.SelectMany(d => d.Props).Where(prop => prop == null); 
//Assign
foreach(var prop in nullProps)
     doc1.Prop[prop.Name] = doc2.Prop[prop.Name];
```

Comment: It appears your LINQ sugestion requires the properties in a list  But if the instance of the document is just a bunch of automatic properties, how do I load them in a list?

Comment: For Linq only the interface IEnumerable<T> is required. So the best thing I could think of create a temporary Enumerable (i.e. a list) and add all properties into it. You could create it with a method on the document like this: List<Property> lst = doc.GetPropertiesAsList();

That way you can use LINQ for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Null coalesce could at least simplify the assignment blocks:

```
DocumentA.FirstProperty = DocumentB.FirstProperty ?? DocumentA.FirstProperty;
```